# Use zoom controls to zoom to point that is not center of map - GoogleMaps V2

Tags: android, google-maps

Here's a weird one.  The zoom controls (+ and -) only function to zoom in and out of the current center of the map.  Is there a way to set these zoom controls to zoom in and out of another point on the screen that is not the center of the map? The only thing I can think of that kind of accomplishes this is to implement an OnCameraChangeListener and have a CameraUpdate to recenter the map every time the zoom level changes.  I don't think I need any code to explain this, but let me know if that would help..

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to this using Canvas class by extending it through SurfaceView. Here is a small code snippet for this:

```
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();

    canvas.scale(mScaleVector.z, mScaleVector.z); // This is the scale factor as seen below
    canvas.translate(mScaleVector.x, mScaleVector.y); // These are offset values from 0,0, both working fine

    // Start draw code

    // ...

    // End draw code

    canvas.restore();
    }
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float factor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        if (Math.abs(factor - 1.0f) >= 0.0075f) {
            mScaleVector.z *= factor;
            mScaleVector.z = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(mScaleVector.z, MAX_ZOOM));
        }

        // ...

        invalidate();

        return true;
    }
    }
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
    if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN && pointerIndex == 1) {
            // The various pivot coordinate codes would belong here
        }
    }

    detector.onTouchEvent(event); // Calls the Scale Gesture Detector
    return true;
}
```

Now this will zoom in to the coordinates (0,0) which is the origin or the top left of the screen also known as the pivot points. To change the pivot points change this line to the required zoom points in your code.

```
canvas.scale(x, y, px, py);
```

Hope this would help!!